# Understanding ENVI images Display mode

Tags: envi, display

A Sentinel-1 image shown in ENVI is 41% in scale(Fig.1,normal) and 51% in scale(Fig.2, unnormal with mussy in black or white dots).

I don't know the reason for the situation, the pyramid-building error or other reasons?

[image]

```
                                         Fig.1
```

[image]

```
                                         Fig.2
```

Comment: I think pyramid setting leads to the problem.